# Pass data between 2 views without segues

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swrevealviewcontroller

I have 2 views, a login view and a main view.

I use SWRevealViewController, and I want automatically display my menu at the startup of the app. I know how display my menu but I don't know how display it just once at startup.

I want to pass a simple String between my Login view and my Main view but  without segue, and made a simple test :

```
 if (myPreviousView == "LoginView")
 {
      // display my menu
 }
```

Comment: If you're not using a segue, how are you changing views (or view controllers)?

Comment: I use a segue, but I can't pass data with it because in my prepareForSegue() if I cast my navigationController in my MainView type, I got error because I display my Menu which is a MenuView type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method would be to use NSUserDefault to store your string, which than can be accessed from anywhere within the application.

So, you put your string into NSUserDefaults in your first view:

```
// Initialize the NSUserDefaults object and an array for data storage
NSUserDefaults *defsData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Add your string to the custom array
NSString *myString = @"My string.";
[myArray addObject:myString];

// Put the array back into UserDefaults for later use
[defsData setObject:myArray forKey:@"Key"]; // Key can be anything
[defsData synchronize];
```

Now, the array (and the string in it) is available anywhere. So, when you navigate to your second view controller, just initialize an NSUserDefaults and access the string:

```
NSUserDefaults* defsData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *myArray = [defsData objectForKey:@"Key"];

NSLog("This is my stored string: %@", [myArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the method :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the init method of your second view controller to take a custom attribute when you subclass it. So, lets say you created a standard UIViewController (.h and .m files). You can modify the init method of this new class to your liking in the .h file:

```
- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)string;
```

And then replace the standard init with the new one in the .m:

```
- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)string {
}
```

So, when you call your view controller into existence, you just use this new init method and pass the string you wanted like this:

```
UIViewController *viewController    = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithString:myString];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

This is a programmatical approach of course, but it should be applied to interface builder easily (unfortunately, as I never use interface builder, I don't know how exactly, but as I said, it should be fairly straightforward to anyone who uses it).